# How to control binding of local variables in Scilab?

Tags: binding, scope, scilab

I have a hard time to describe my problem. Look at the end for an example.

I have a function `G` that uses another function `F`. In order use to the function `F` I need to define a new (local/nested) function `g`. The function `g` depends on local (to `G`) variables with common names as `A`, `b`, `x` etc. The trouble is that these variable names are also used in `F`. Since Scilabs function calls seems to be some form of macro expansion that binds local variables at the point of calling/expansion instead of the point where the function is defined the values of the local variables in `F` are used instead of the ones in `G`. Can I define the function `g`in another way to bind the variables at the site of definition?

```
function y = F(f,x)
    k = -10
    y = f(x)
endfunction


function [a, b] = G(u)
    k = u
    deff('y = g(x)','y = x + k')

    k = 10
    a = g(1)
    b = F(g,1)
endfunction

[a b] = G(0)
disp(a)
disp(b)
```

This program displays the values `11.` and `-9.`. I would like it to display `1.` and `1.`. The problem is that the binding of the local variable `k` in `f` is decided, not at the point of the  definition of `f`, but at the point of calling/expanding `f`. How do I define a local function `g` that binds its local variables at the point of definition?

The example is only a small working example. In reality my function `g` lokks something like this

```
    function y = g(x), y = t*h0(x) + A'*diag(d.^2)*A, endfunction
```

where `t` is a scalar, `h0` is a function `A` a matrix and `d` a vector are local to `G`. The input parameter `x` is a vector. The matrices and vectors can have dimensions up to 1000x1000 and 1000 and be dense.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [sprintf](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.3.3/en_US/sprintf.html) to insert the value as string so it is 'defined' instantly, or use the [string()](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.3.3/en_US/string.html) operator.

### Working example

```
function y = F(f,x)
    k = -10
    y = f(x) 
endfunction

function [a, b] = G(u)
    k = u

    // Using the sprintf operator 
    deff('y = g(x)',sprintf('y = x + %d',k) )

    // Using the string operator 
    deff('y = g(x)','y = x +' + string(k) )

    k = 10
    a = g(1)
    b = F(g,1) 
endfunction

[a b] = G(0)

disp(a) 
disp(b)
```

Comment: Interesting. How do I use `sprintf`with matrices, vectors and functions instead of scalars as parameters?

Comment: You could also use the [string()](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.3.3/en_US/string.html) operator which 'converts a matrix into a matrix of strings.' It will convert the matrix into a string of the current actual values.